# text moving to the next line python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

This is my first attempt at writing something in Python.  I'm not understanding why the text is going to the next line.  I want it to be:

**Would you like to delete "event"?

 Y or N**

But it prints as:

**Would you like to delete "event

"? 
 Y or N**

Thanks

```
# picks a random string from ideas34.txt
event = random.choice(open('ideas34.txt', 'r').readlines())

choice = int(input('\n' "What would you like to do?" '\n' "1  Random event" '\n' "2  Add a new event" '\n'
                   "3  Show all events" '\n' "4  Quit" '\n'))
# prints a random event from ideas34.txt
if choice == 1:
    print(event)
    d = input("Would you like to delete " "\"" + event + "\"? \n Y or N" '\n')
    # deletes the event picked
    if d == 'Y' or d == 'y':
        f = open('ideas34.txt', 'r')
        a = [event]
        lst = []
        for line in f:
            for word in a:
                if word in line:
                    line = line.replace(word, '')   # deletes event picked from ideas34.txt
            lst.append(line)
        f.close()
        f = open('ideas34.txt', 'w')
        for line in lst:
            f.write(line)
        f.close()
```

Comment: May b coz you have `\n` before ? Y or N

Comment: Hint: `.readlines()` retains the newlines on the lines it reads. There are a few ways to deal with that, but take a look at the `str` type's `.strip` and `.rstrip` methods.

Comment: @PM 2Ring    Thank you, that was it.  `event.rstrip()` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the mixing up of the single and double quotes, then escaping the **newLine** and the double quote all together in the same line

try instead something like

```
input('Would you like to delete ' '\"' + event + '\"?' '\n' Y or N' '\n')
```